Azure Function App creation using New-AzFunctionApp through powershell
I'm creating a function app using PowerShell.
How can I avoid the step of getting function app plans even if I have not used get-azappserviceplan?

enter image description here
$functionAppName = "funcAppName"
$resourceGroupName = "RESGroup"
$appLocation = "region"
$storageName = "stgAccName"

# Connect to Azure 
$secret = "xxx"
$appID = "xxx"
$TenantId = "xxx"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $secret -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $appID, $SecurePassword

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantID $TenantId -Credential $credentials

# to create functionapp
New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $functionAppName -Location $appLocation -Tier "Basic"
New-AzFunctionApp $functionAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Plan $functionAppName -Runtime Node -StorageAccountName $storageName -FunctionsVersion 4 -OS Windows

This are the command/ script.
I added an attribute in New-AzFunctionApp as -NoWait still its running that step


The step of getting functionapp plans even if I have not used get-azappserviceplan

Even though you have not used Get-AzAppServicePlan, When setting the plan to the function app, the command will eventually search for the plan you have given i n the command, it will not take directly without getting the plan first. It will take all the details of the plan then link it with function app.

Then only function app will be created:
$rithfunc = "rithwik766"
$rith_rg = ""
$Loc = "East US"
$st = "rithwik"
$x=New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $rith_rg -Name $rithfunc -Location $Loc -Tier "Basic"
New-AzFunctionApp -Name $rithfunc -ResourceGroupName $rith_rg -PlanName $x.Name -StorageAccountName $st -FunctionsVersion 4 -OS Windows -Runtime PowerShell



Hi @RithwikBojja, Thanks for input but tried the same but it still command is searching for service plan any other suggestion??
I have kept functionAppName and plan name same

It will search as it is the behavior of that command
